# Google Forms Apps Script API to Enable Email Notification For New Responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a method available in the FormApp API that will allow the "Email Notification For New Responses" feature to be enabled. I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find any method in the Forms object that provided access to this form setting. I know this can be easily implemented by using triggers but if it has already been implemented no point reimplementing it. You can see the screenshot highlighting the option that is available in the form UI:

[image].

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation either.